# Node js: Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I'm currently coding a webapp with Javascript and i wrote this:

```
const fs = require('fs')

function jsonReader(filepath, cb) {
  fs.readFile(filepath, 'utf-8', (err, fileData) => {
    if (err) {
      return cb && cb(err);
    }
    try {
      const Object = JSON.parse(fileData);
      return cb && cb(null, Object);
    } catch (err) {
      return cb && cb(err)
    }
  })
}
```

This is just a function that parses the data from the json file.
But the problem with the require is that the console always says:
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined.
Can someone help me out there because I'm really new to Node js and also Javascript!

Comment: Are you sure you're running it in node? and not a browser? Please share how you run this code?

Comment: If you are running this in Node.js (v15 or earlier), it sounds like you've written this code in a project that has `"type": "module"` in `package.json`, and so doesn't use `require` ([CommonJS](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html)), but instead uses the now-standard [ESM](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html). (Or you have `.mjs` as the extension on the file, which also tells Node.js to use ESM.) (I said "v15 or earlier" because in v16 you get a much more helpful message: *"ReferenceError: require is not defined in ES module scope, you can use import instead"*).

Comment: (If you're running this in a browser instead of Node.js, you won't have access to the `fs` module regardless of the module syntax you're using. Browsers don't allow direct file access, for perhaps obvious security reasons.)

Comment: Thanks for the replys @T.J.Crowder and @evolutionxbox! I'm running this in my Browser(Firefox) and I don't have ''Type': 'module' in package.json. I also have Node.js (V16). So how can i access the the file?

Comment: @Gur.js - Again, you can't directly access files from browser-hosted JavaScript code, for security reasons. Also note that browsers don't provide access to the Node.js API, which is for use in local applications and servers.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder- Can i put my Data in a database so i can change it from there? (Sorry if it's a dumb question. I'm really a noob in js and Node js :) )

Comment: If you run the code in a browser you're not using node at all